# Passing parameter to a user control which is bound to a gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a user control named ActivityGrid which takes a list of object as a parameter in it's constructor.

```
public ActivityGrid(List<clsActivityRow> ActivityData)
{
   bindData(ActivityData);
}
```

I need to bind this user control in a gridView called parentGrid, so I used Templatefield.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridViewParent" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns ="False">
<Columns>
   <asp:TemplateField>
      <ItemTemplate>
         <tr>
            <td colspan="100%">
               <uc1:ActivityGrid ID="ActivityGrid1" runat="server" />
            </td>
         </tr>
      </ItemTemplate>
   </asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

> How do I pass the list of object in this user control while it is
>   bound inside a gridview?

I have the list of object `List<clsActivityRow> ActivityData` ready in the code behind.

Comment: User controls should not have/use constructors that take arguments. It does not fit well within the WebForms model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to find the ActivityGrid1 `object` in *every row* of `GridViewParent` in its `RowDataBound` event and assign `datasource`.

```
protected void GridViewParent_RowDataBound(Object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{           
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {                
          ActivityGrid ActivityGrid1= (ActivityGrid )e.Row.FindControl("ActivityGrid1");                    
                if (ActivityGrid1 != null)
                {
                    ActivityGrid1.DataSource = SomeMethodToReturnDataSource();                       
                    ActivityGrid1.DataBind();
                }
         }          
}
```

or if your control has grid view i.e ActivityGrid1 has gridView1 then you can find gridView1 in ActivityGrid1

```
protected void GridViewParent_RowDataBound(Object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{           
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {                
          ActivityGrid ActivityGrid1= (ActivityGrid )e.Row.FindControl("ActivityGrid1");                    
                if (ActivityGrid1 != null)
                {
                    GridView gridView1 = (ActivityGrid )ActivityGrid1 .FindControl("gridView1");    
                    gridView1.DataSource = SomeMethodToReturnDataSource();                          
                    gridView1.DataBind();
                }
         }          
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by creating a public Property in your UserControl and In this public property set block you can call bindData method.

Pass the object List ActiveData for this usercontrol, in GridView RowDataBound Event.